# AWS Cloudtrail - Access Key IDs Randomly Generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

[image]

Requesting for inputs here. I am trying to learn AWS, passed Practitioner. I tried to Google and the max I could find was -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-console.html

AWS access key

```
The AWS access key ID that was used to sign the request. If the request was made with temporary security credentials, this is the access key ID of the temporary credentials.
```

What are those temporary (??) keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Temporary security credentials in IAM - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html):

> You can use the AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS) to create and provide trusted users with temporary security credentials that can control access to your AWS resources. Temporary security credentials work almost identically to long-term access key credentials, with the following differences:
>
> - Temporary security credentials are **short-term**, as the name implies. They can be configured to last for anywhere from a few minutes to several hours. After the credentials expire, AWS no longer recognizes them or allows any kind of access from API requests made with them.
> - Temporary security credentials are not stored with the user but are **generated dynamically** and provided to the user when requested. When (or even before) the temporary security credentials expire, the user can request new credentials, as long as the user requesting them still has permissions to do so.
>
> As a result, temporary credentials have the following advantages over long-term credentials:
>
> - You do not have to distribute or embed long-term AWS security credentials with an application.
> - You can provide access to your AWS resources to users without having to define an AWS identity for them. Temporary credentials are **the basis for roles and identity federation**.
> - The temporary security credentials have a **limited lifetime**, so you do not have to rotate them or explicitly revoke them when they're no longer needed. After temporary security credentials expire, they cannot be reused. You can specify how long the credentials are valid, up to a maximum limit.

Access Keys starting with `AKIA` are long-term credentials, typically associated with an **IAM User**.

Access Keys starting with `ASIA` are temporary credentials created by AWS STS. They also require a **session token** in addition to the **secret key**. You will mostly see these when **assuming an IAM Role**.

See: [IAM identifiers - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids)

Comment: Thank you so much John! All I wanted was the documentation to learn myself but you went a step ahead! Appreciate it, have a great week!